# How to make the events in fullCalendar display in 12H not 24H format

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, time-format

I have a bunch of calendars all coming from Google calendars on a site and everything works great aside from the the events displaying in 24h format.

I have tried to set it in the jQuery code but I can't figure out the right code to do that. In the Google calendar settings they're all set in 12H so it has to be something in `fullCalendar`.

This is the only code I can find when I do a search and it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)t',
    timezone: 'America/Toronto',
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'hidden',
    eventSources: [{
      googleCalendarId: 'hidden',
      className: 'calendar'
    }]
  });
});
```

Is `timeFormat` the correct line to control it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `timeFormat` option is the correct thing to set.

Now you need to [consult the momentJS documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (linked to from this [fullCalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting-string) (which is in turn linked from the [timeFormat documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeFormat))) to know what format string you can use to get the times shown in your desired format.

For example:

```
timeFormat: "HH:mm"
```

will get you 24hr times such as `21:00` etc. You can amend this yourself if you need it to show something slightly different.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8bx14goh/